# async / await does not wait for task to finish

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I am trying to set up bi-directional streaming with gRPC. I have followed their tutorials, and have read the other solutions on Stack Overflow, but none of that seems to resolve my issue.

For testing purposes, I created a simple button-click event meant to kick this all off as below. While I await all my calls, `message` is disposed before the await `resultTask` is completed. As I understand it, the `await` operator should sit around until completion of the `resultTask` before completing the scope.

Can someone assist in outlining what I am doing wrong here?

```
    private async void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await CallServer();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _box.Text = exception.Message;
        }

    }

    private static async Task CallServer()
    {
        Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001"));

        using var message = client.Echos();

        var resultTask = Task.Run(action: (async () =>
        {

            while (await message.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
            {
                //Write out the result of the response
            }

        }));

        List<HelloRequest> hellos = new List<HelloRequest>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            hellos.Add(new HelloRequest() { Name = i.ToString() });
        }

        foreach (var hello in hellos)
        {
            await message.RequestStream.WriteAsync(hello);
        }

        await message.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
        await resultTask;
    }
}
```

Some more info:

1. .net-core 3.1 for both the form and the web service.
2. client is connecting to the service via grpc.net.client

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know the communication works, because if I do something like a Console.ReadKey() or I replace `using var message = client.Echos()` with `var message = client.Echos()` the messages return fine (but it still doesn't await).

That said, here is the proto:

> syntax = "proto3";
> option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService1";
>
> package greet;
>
> service Greeter {
> rpc Echos (stream HelloRequest) returns (stream .greet.HelloReply);
> }
>
> message HelloRequest {
> string name = 1;
> }
>
> message HelloReply {
> string message = 1;
> }

And the server code:

```
public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
    public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task Echos(IAsyncStreamReader<HelloRequest> requestStream, IServerStreamWriter<HelloReply> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
        {
            await responseStream.WriteAsync(new HelloReply() {Message = "Hello " + requestStream.Current.Name});
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `await` works fine. `resultTask` *listens* for responses and will terminate if the server closes the stream. If anything, `resultTask` is the wrong name. The rest of the code sends 10 messages in a tight loop. Perhaps the server closed the stream, eg due to an error? What does the server do?

Comment: BTW since you use `using var` you could use `await foreach(var response in message.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())`

Comment: It looks like you've modified the code from [Call gRPC services with the .NET client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#make-grpc-calls). You'll have to provide a complete example of both the client and server, since the original example can't be used to identify what's wrong with your code. Unless there's an exception that wasn't logged, the server ends the response stream prematurely. Without the server code, we can only guess

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - thanks for the feedback - please find the updated details. As I mentioned in the edit - I believe the communication between client and server works because I get results if I block the method somehow or remove the scope. If there is a better way of doing this I am open to suggestions. The final product would be used to send requests to the server and wait for the server to return completed results.

Comment: Also, I based the client code off the bidirectional code at the bottom of the page. https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/basics/

Comment: this line ( async void ) is not true and it's not wait for async method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, I managed to resolve the issue by refactoring the method that wasn't completing the await. I removed the `Task.Run` and replaced it with an `async` method that returns a value:

```
        private async Task CallServer()
    {
        Greeter.GreeterClient client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001"));

        using var message = client.Echos();

        var resultTask = CompletedTask(message);

        List<HelloRequest> hellos = new List<HelloRequest>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            hellos.Add(new HelloRequest() { Name = i.ToString() });
        }

        foreach (var hello in hellos)
        {
            await message.RequestStream.WriteAsync(hello);
        }

        await message.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
        var x = await resultTask;
        _box.Text += "Done!";
    }

    private async Task<bool> CompletedTask(AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<HelloRequest, HelloReply> message)
    {
        await foreach (var result in message.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            _box.Text += result.Message + @"\r\n";
        }

        return true;
    }
```

`Task.Run` was returning a method signature with return type of `void` which is why it wasn't awaiting an answer. Changing it to reference a method with a return type solved the issue.